# How to programmatically decide if smtpappender must send mail

Tags: log4net

I have a c# program that logs with log4net both on file appender and smtp appender.

I would like to keep always the log file but at the end of the program in my c# code I would like to decide if I have to send the email or not.

The usual level or text filters do not help here since while the program runs I log a lot of stuff that may be interesting or not and I know that only at the end of the process.

Is it possible to "block" the smtp appender by code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Threshold property on the appender to OFF to disable logging, and to your required value otherwise, something like this:

```
private static void SetEmailLogging(bool enabled)
{
    // Assuming there aren't more than 1 SmtpAppenders
    var appender = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository()
                                     .GetAppenders()
                                     .OfType<SmtpAppender>()
                                     .SingleOrDefault();

    if (appender == null)
    { 
        return;       
    }

    // Set the level you want.
    appender.Threshold = enabled ? Level.All : Level.Off;

    appender.ActivateOptions();
}
```